# Spring boot not creating schema correctly?

Tags: spring-boot, h2

I have very simple spring boot app which is using h2 database on local. I have schema-h2.sql which has below script -

```
CREATE TABLE USERS(
  userid NUMBER(10,0) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  email   VARCHAR(256) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  fname   VARCHAR(256),
  lname   VARCHAR(256)
);
```

And in application-default.properties -

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.platform=h2
```

`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;MODE=MSSQLServer;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLO SE_ON_EXIT=false`

When I look at /h2-console, I can see table being created but it is missing unique constraint on email column.

I even tried adding alter statement in schema-h2.sql script to create constraint but that doesn't work either -

```
ALTER TABLE USERS ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_EMAIL UNIQUE(email);
```

Also, when run those script in h2-console it creates unique constraint correctly so it does seem like something to do with how spring executes them.

When debugging I can see that Alter statement gets executed without any exception in ScriptUtils class.

Not sure how to take this forward so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I am using spring-boot v1.3.5

Comment: Can anyone help with this one?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else coming across this, I was able to fix it by altering my JPA annotation. Adding the `unique` parameter **in addition to** creating the constraint in `h2-schema.sql` allowed the constraint to actually be created.

```
@Column(name = "email", unique = true, nullable = false)
private String email;
```

Answer (score 0):

If schema is beign created by spring boot with schema.sql file, make sure to disable hibernate schema auto create:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

Otherwise, Hibernate will overwritte it everytime the app starts.